# How to see the commands that are executed by a silent cmd.exe

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, task-manager, windows-server-2003, ms-dos

The cmd.exe process is taking up resources on a server, I would like to see what it is running.
How can I do it?

[Task Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dWAI.png)

Comment: What is the operating system?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Best way in my opinion would be to use [process explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer), but looks like you'll need to find an older version. Using this you'll be able to simply hover over cmd.exe in the list and see what file actually called it, which will include the file path.  Then you could simply go directly to the file, open it up in notepad and read it.